How to set the learning rate of BGD in sklearn's LogisticRegression?
Is it possible to define a learning rate when using sklearn's LogisticRegression?
I know it is possible to define the learning rate when using SGDClassifier, but that class does not implement BGD. So, I would like to know if than can be done in LogistRegression.

Does this answer your question? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16751/learning-rate-in-logistic-regression-with-sklearn
...or this: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/116456/difference-between-sklearns-logisticregression-and-sgdclassifier
